# Nodemailer ECONNREFUSED localhost

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I can't find a solution to this error, i'm running locally i already checked if there are services using the ports but there is none

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1093:14)
      code: 'ECONNECTION',
      errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 465,
      command: 'CONN' }
```

Heres my setting

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PWD
    }
  });
```

Also running `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smpt.gmail.com:465` doesn't return anything both on 465 and 587

Answer (score 4):

u added the host on the service...
try this

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport'); // this is important

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  auth: {
    user: 'somerealemail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'realpasswordforaboveaccount'
  }
}));

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'somerealemail@gmail.com',
  to: 'friendsgmailacc@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js[nodemailer]',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

then if needed enable "lesssecureapps" by clicking this [link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)